# How to load local image choosen by user in React 360

Tags: reactjs, google-vr, 360-panorama

Im using React-360 to display a 360 photo. It works fine when we give remote url as src in `Environment.setBackgroundImage(src, {format: format});`

But i have a requirement to allow user to select a local 360 photo file and preview it.

Using Input tag and javascript i'm getting the file choose by user; but i'm not able to pass that file as src.

i tried this too.. didn't work.

```
src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
Environment.setBackgroundImage(src, {format: format});
```

Is it not possible to load local file in react 360.

Same Problem in google vr view also. Anything i can do to load local file choose by user.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz demo to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the `asset` method like so?

```
Environment.setBackgroundImage(asset('your_image.jpg'));
```

I think this could be what you are looking for.